# Get a total of employees on the clock every 10 minutes of the day

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

I am having a big problem, I have a table that has counts of employees the clocked in a a specific time rounded off to 15 minute increments each day.  Included in the table are the end times.  I am trying to create a bar graph which shows the 15 minutes time windows along the X axis and the Y axis should show the total number of people on the clock at that time however all I can get it to show is how many people "clocked in" at each of those spans.  I'm not sure what I am doing wrong.  I made a separate time table in 15 minute increments and related it to the employee table and still, same result.  ANy help would be greatly appreciated!!!

I am using a simple measure to get the sum.  SUMEMPCNT=SUM('data'{EMPCNT])

Here is a sample of the data table:

[image]

Here is a sample of the current chart.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the build in **Quick Measure** "Runnung total" to get your DAX formula:

[image]

It will give you this measure:

```
Number running total in TimeStamp = 
CALCULATE(
    SUM('Table'[Number]),
    FILTER(
        ALLSELECTED('Table'[TimeStamp]),
        ISONORAFTER('Table'[TimeStamp], MAX('Table'[TimeStamp]), DESC)
    )
)
```

that you can visualize in a clustered column chart:

[image]

Comment: Thank you Peter!  This is great!  Just what I was looking for.  May I ask you a side question?  What are the chances of being able to not only keep running total but also subtract once people reach their clock out time??  Thanks again!!